# Backup Ubuntu Server with Azure

Tags: azure, ubuntu, backup, azure-storage, ubuntu-server

I want make an automatic Backup of our Samba(Ubuntu) Server.
This automatic backup should go over to an Azure(Ubuntu) Server.

So how must I configure our local server that it backup the Data and send it to Server at Azure?
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1NNL.png)

Edit:
The working Solution for me was with Azure Blob Storage and a cron job.

Comment: You could use Azure Recovery Services to backup your VM. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-backup-vms

Comment: But  the backup points don't store on your VM, if you need, you could upload it to your VM.

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT Thanks to your Suggestion, but i want make a backup to an Azure Server and not a Backup off an Azure Server

Comment: I don't think store backup points on a VM is a good idea. Do you want to backup files on other VMs to the ubuntu VM?

Comment: No i want backup our local FTP-Server to an Azure Ubuntu Server.
This is for the case when our Server Room starts buring that we not lose all Data.

Comment: You local server is a physic machine a VM on Hyper-V? This Sever is also a Ubuntu?

Comment: I suggest you could backup your local files to Azure storage account, it is more cheaper. See this [blog](https://lnx.azurewebsites.net/backup-encrypted-data-from-linux-servers-directly-to-azure-blob-storage/).

Comment: physic machine with Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Based on my experience, you could backup your data to Azure blob, it is cheaper. You only need pay for storage account cost. For a VM, you need pay for the VM and storage account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you could backup your local files to Azure blob. Compared to a Azure VM, it is more cheaper, you only need pay for the storage account cost.

You could check this [blog:backup data from Linux Servers to Azure blob Storage](https://lnx.azurewebsites.net/backup-encrypted-data-from-linux-servers-directly-to-azure-blob-storage/).

You could a task to upload your files to Azure automatic.

Comment: I will look, give it's a pricing list to Azure Storage?

Comment: See this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/blobs/), you only need pay you used.

Comment: Hi, does it work for you? Please let me know if you need more future help :--).

Comment: No panic on the titanic, i will mark it when i had time to try it out

Comment: Fine, if you have question about this, please let me know.

Comment: Hey, it worked fine, I have only one problem. It's delete the connector when i reboot the server and this is a big problem. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux

Comment: And i use the persistent mount.